# Visual Studio Code Language Server - how to validate all files in workspace

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I followed this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server) from the visual studio code on how to create a language server to a validate an extension file. I proceeded to make a copy of the lsp-sample project and got it running.

In my analysis of this project, I noticed that only open or changed files in the workspace are validated.

```
// The content of a text document has changed. This event is emitted
// when the text document first opened or when its content has changed.        
documents.onDidChangeContent((change) => { 
    validateTextDocument(change.document);
});
```

This is all fine for most cases, but I think that when the workspace is opened all files (regardless of being open by the editor or not) should be validated in order to have a richer IDE experiencie in vscode.

Can anyone experienced in the Language Server protocol help me on how to do this? As far as I know the "documents" object is only populated with opened files.

Many thanks,
Ricardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inspect the `rootPath` or `rootUri` from the initial `initialize` request from the client. From there, you can validate all of its files and report errors as necessary. Of course, it is possible that both of those are `null`.

If the client supports workspace folders, then you will need to interact with the `workspace/workspaceFolders` and `workspace/didChangeWorkspaceFolders` and extract the relevant information from there to determine how to validate your files.

Comment: @ricardo-ferreira-da-silva - can you share more about how you solved this one? Were you able to get the document list into a `TextDocuments<TextDocument>` stream?